# Using an image in the Settings Bundle of an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, settings.bundle

Is it possible and how can you embed an image into your own app's settings bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.** Have you seen this done in any other apps from the App Store? And I am not referring to the built-in iOS apps or even jailbroken preference bundles.

The ONLY icon you have control over is the icon you see before you go into your settings. This is changed when you change the icon of the app itself. **icon@2x.png** for example.

Comment: No, I hadn't seen it done but had seen TextFields, switches and other UI elements in it, so I thought I would ask to see if anyone thought or knew it was possible.

Comment: No, image are not possible in Settings bundles.

Comment: How facebook adds image then ?

Comment: Facebook does not add images. In fact, Facebook does not even have a settings bundle. They are integrated into iOS and therefore Apple has created their preference bundle which is what you are seeing.

Comment: From the documentation: "**The Settings Bundle** A Settings bundle has the name Settings.bundle and resides in the top-level directory of your app’s bundle. This bundle contains one or more Settings page files that describe the individual pages of preferences. It may also include other support files needed to display your preferences, such as images or localized strings. Table 4-2 lists the contents of a typical Settings bundle."  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html.

Comment: Although the image (AFAIK) can only be used for the a PSSliderSpecifier item:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/preferencesettings/conceptual/settingsapplicationschemareference/Articles/PSSliderSpecifier.html